# How to extend moment js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I'd like to extend `moment.js`, to override it's `toJSON` function.

```
const moment = require('moment');

class m2 extends moment {
    constructor(data) {
        super(data);
        this.toJSON = function () {
            return 'STR';
        };
    }
}

const json = {
    date: moment(),
};

const json2 = {
    date: new m2(),
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); // {"date":"2017-07-25T13:36:47.023Z"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(json2)); // {"date":"STR"}
```

My problem is that, in this case I can not call `m2()` without `new`:

```
const json3 = {
    date: m2(), // TypeError: Class constructor m2 cannot be invoked without 'new'
};
```

How can I extend `moment` while keeping the ability to call it without the `new` keyword?

Override `moment.prototype.toJSON` is not an option, because I'd like to use the default `moment` object elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Why don't you use a helper function to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to extend the `moment` class at all?  You could set replace the `toJSON` function from a factory function.

```
function m2(data) {
    const original = moment(data);
    original.toJSON = function() {
        return 'STR';
    }
    return original;
}
```

Then use it as you would normally use `moment`

```
const json2 = {
    date: m2(),
};
```

Comment: Didn't you miss the `return` statement of your m2 function ?

Comment: I sure did - fixed now!